# Looping through Jquery UI Tabs

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I'm writing a basic chat application and I used jQuery UI Tabs for showing users' texts.

Now I faced a problem, How i can loop through tabs and find their specific create-time id to ask server about their new message?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

One option is to store the create time id as a `data()` value on the chat tabs.  You can loop through the tab elements by doing something like this:

```
$('#tabs > ul > li').each(function() { 
  var ct = $(this).data('createtime');
});
```